# Reusing ReactJS component in Blade foreach

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm having this component called 'IssueRating' and I want to be able to call this component so that every foreach record could call this 'IssueRating' component. For the moment only the first record is outputing a score.

**Blade template**

```
@foreach($issues as $issue))
      <div class="row>
            <div id="issue-rating" data="{{ $issue->key }}"></div>
            <a href="/{{ $issue->key }}" target="_blank">
                 {{ $issue->fields->summary }}
            </a>
      </div>
@endforeach
```

**React component**

```
class IssueRating extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            score: ""
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("/../api/***/issue/score/"+this.props.data)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        status: "okay",
                        score: result.score,
                    });
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        status: error,
                    });
                }
            )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="test">{this.state.score}</div>
        )
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('issue-rating')) {
    var data = document.getElementById('issue-rating').getAttribute('data');
    ReactDOM.render(<IssueRating data={data}/>, document.getElementById('issue-rating'));
}
```

Comment: Well, your first problem is that IDs are unique; so `id="issue-rating"` would only ever target 1 element, no matter how many times you reuse it :)

Comment: Thanks Tim. I also tried is using HTML classes but got stuck in the process.